# Updating a drop down menu using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to populate a drop down menu following a selection in another menu. when Audi is selected onchange should call the javascript function and populate the second drop down menu with the correct options for Audi models. I cant seem to get the following to work, if anyone one could help it would be great.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome to the homepage</title>
<script>
    function update_model(theForm){   
      theForm=document.frm2;
      var NumModel = theForm.model_id.options.length; 
      var SelectedMake = ''; 
    while(NumModel > 0) {NumModel--; theForm.model_id.options[NumModel] = null;}  
      SelectedMake = theForm.make_id.options[theForm.make_id.selectedIndex].value;  
        if (SelectedMake == "audi") {
           theForm.model_id.options[0] = new Option("* Choose Model *", "");
           theForm.model_id.options[1] = new Option("A1", "A1");
           theForm.model_id.options[2] = new Option("A3", "A3");

       } else  if (SelectedMake == "bmw") {
        theForm.model_id.options[0] = new Option("* Choose Model *", "");
        theForm.model_id.options[1] = new Option("1 SERIES", "1SERIES");
        theForm.model_id.options[2] = new Option("3 SERIES", "3SERIES");
        theForm.model_id.options[3] = new Option("5 SERIES", "5SERIES");
        theForm.model_id.options[4] = new Option("6 SERIES", "6SERIES");
        theForm.model_id.options[5] = new Option("7 SERIES", "7SERIES");
        theForm.model_id.options[6] = new Option("X1", "X1");
        theForm.model_id.options[7] = new Option("X3", "X3");
        theForm.model_id.options[8] = new Option("X5", "X5");
        theForm.model_id.options[9] = new Option("Z3", "Z3");
        theForm.model_id.options[10] = new Option("Z4", "Z4");
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h2>Welcome to the homepage</h2>
        <br><br> 
        <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="window.location='Login.jsp'">
        <input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="window.location='Registration.jsp'">
        <br><br>
        <label>
            <select  name="make_id"  onchange="update_model(this.form);"  class="dbsearchform1">
            <option value=''> *Choose Make*</option>
            <option value="audi" >Audi</option>
            <option value="bmw" >BMW</option>
            <option value="ford" >Ford</option>
            <option value="toyota" >Toyota</option>
        </select>

        <select name="model_id" id="model_id" class="istyle" >
            <option value='' >*Choose Model*</option>
        </select> 
    </label>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this http://jsfiddle.net/QLYwp/

**HTML**

```
    <center>
        <h2>Welcome to the homepage</h2>
        <br><br> 
        <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="window.location='Login.jsp'">
        <input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="window.location='Registration.jsp'">
        <br><br>
        <label>
            <select  name="make_id" id="make_id" onchange="update_model();"  class="dbsearchform1">
            <option value=''> *Choose Make*</option>
            <option value="audi" >Audi</option>
            <option value="bmw" >BMW</option>
            <option value="ford" >Ford</option>
            <option value="toyota" >Toyota</option>
        </select>

        <select name="model_id" id="model_id" class="istyle" >
            <option value='' >*Choose Model*</option>
        </select> 
    </label>

</center>
```

**JS**

```
function update_model(){   
    var model_id = document.getElementById("model_id");
    var make_id = document.getElementById("make_id");
      var NumModel = model_id.options.length; 
      var SelectedMake = ''; 
    while(NumModel > 0) {NumModel--; model_id.options[NumModel] = null;}  
      SelectedMake = make_id.options[make_id.selectedIndex].value;  
        if (SelectedMake == "audi") {
           model_id.options[0] = new Option("* Choose Model *", "");
           model_id.options[1] = new Option("A1", "A1");
           model_id.options[2] = new Option("A3", "A3");

       } else  if (SelectedMake == "bmw") {
        model_id.options[0] = new Option("* Choose Model *", "");
        model_id.options[1] = new Option("1 SERIES", "1SERIES");
        model_id.options[2] = new Option("3 SERIES", "3SERIES");
        model_id.options[3] = new Option("5 SERIES", "5SERIES");
        model_id.options[4] = new Option("6 SERIES", "6SERIES");
        model_id.options[5] = new Option("7 SERIES", "7SERIES");
        model_id.options[6] = new Option("X1", "X1");
        model_id.options[7] = new Option("X3", "X3");
        model_id.options[8] = new Option("X5", "X5");
        model_id.options[9] = new Option("Z3", "Z3");
        model_id.options[10] = new Option("Z4", "Z4");
 }
}
```

The main issue is that you need to use document.getElementById to reference elements on the page.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you were doing it wrong with getting your select boxes elements. But anyways... Your javascript function should look like this:

```
function update_model(){  
    var makeEl=document.getElementById("make_id");  
    var modelEl=document.getElementById("model_id");
    var NumModel = modelEl.options.length; 
    var SelectedMake = ''; 

    while(NumModel > 0) {NumModel--; modelEl.options[NumModel] = null;}  

    SelectedMake = makeEl.options[makeEl.selectedIndex].value;  
    if (SelectedMake == "audi") {
        modelEl.options[0] = new Option("* Choose Model *", "");
        modelEl.options[1] = new Option("A1", "A1");
        modelEl.options[2] = new Option("A3", "A3");

    } 
    else if (SelectedMake == "bmw") {
        modelEl.options[0] = new Option("* Choose Model *", "");
        modelEl.options[1] = new Option("1 SERIES", "1SERIES");
        modelEl.options[2] = new Option("3 SERIES", "3SERIES");
        modelEl.options[3] = new Option("5 SERIES", "5SERIES");
        modelEl.options[4] = new Option("6 SERIES", "6SERIES");
        modelEl.options[5] = new Option("7 SERIES", "7SERIES");
        modelEl.options[6] = new Option("X1", "X1");
        modelEl.options[7] = new Option("X3", "X3");
        modelEl.options[8] = new Option("X5", "X5");
        modelEl.options[9] = new Option("Z3", "Z3");
        modelEl.options[10] = new Option("Z4", "Z4");
    }             
}
```

Also add an id to your "make" select box

```
<select id="make_id" name="make_id" onchange="update_model();" >
    <option value=''> *Choose Make*</option>
    <option value="audi" >Audi</option>
    <option value="bmw" >BMW</option>
    <option value="ford" >Ford</option>
    <option value="toyota" >Toyota</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I've tried your changes and it still does not work nothing is appearing in the second dropdown menu, any other suggestion to what may be causing this?

Comment: @SteveK Did you add that id to the make_id <select> ? For the future do use browser's console and see what Javascript errors you are getting :)

Comment: yes i did and there is no errors appearing in the console the server just starts up and thats it

Comment: That's strange... There's was a similar answer submitted by another guy right below mine. It has a jsfiddle link. Looks like the code works very well. I am not sure why it's causing trouble now.

Comment: AVK, I apologize if I intercepted your answer, but I created that JSFiddle example at the same time you were answering, and thought it would be a waste not to post it.

Comment: It's alright @Dave. As long as the problem is solved. Wonder why it wouldn't work with my answer, because the our pieces of code are almost identical :)

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way instead. How you are doing it now with the call in the html is kind of wonky. If you bind the change event to a listener you will see results much more easily. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3faJ5/)

html will look the same except second dropdown also has an id:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to the homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
         <h2>Welcome to the homepage</h2>

        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="window.location='Login.jsp'">
        <input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="window.location='Registration.jsp'">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>
            <select id="make_id" name="make_id" class="dbsearchform1">
                <option value=''>*Choose Make*</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
                <option value="ford">Ford</option>
                <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
            </select>
            <select name="model_id" id="model_id" class="istyle">
                <option value=''>*Choose Model*</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript will now look like this:

```
var form1 = document.getElementById('make_id');
form1.addEventListener('change', update_model);
var audi_List = [
    'A1',
    'A3', ]
var bmw_list = [
    '1 SERIES',
    '3 SERIES',
    '5 SERIES',
    '6 SERIES',
    '7 SERIES',
    'X1',
    'X3',
    'X5',
    'Z3',
    'Z4', ]

function update_model(e) {
    var value = e.target.value;
    var theForm = document.getElementById('model_id');
    theForm.innerHTML = '';
    theForm.options[0] = new Option('*Choose Model*', '');
    switch (value) {
        case 'audi':
            for (i = 0; i < audi_List.length; i++) {
                theForm.options[i+1] = new Option(audi_List[i], audi_List[i]);
            }
            break;
        case 'bmw':
            for (i = 1; i < bmw_list.length; i++) {
                theForm.options[i] = new Option(bmw_list[i], bmw_list[i]);
            }
            break;
        case 'ford':
            for (i = 1; i < ford_list.length; i++) {
                theForm.options[i] = new Option(bmw_list[i], bmw_list[i]);
            }
            break;
        case 'toyota':
            for (i = 1; i < toyota_list.length; i++) {
                theForm.options[i] = new Option(bmw_list[i], bmw_list[i]);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I put all of the values in an array because there isn't enough time in life to type out that many individual Option classes. Also you can list any other things, put them in an array, and use this same function to update other dropdowns with a few changes. Just specify your ford_list and toyota_list and you'll be good to go.